# Create Mongoid Document from Hash

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have model:

```
class Task
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :name, type: String
    field :category, type: String
    # ....
```

And I have a method to create new documents:

```
def self.create_task(hash)
        Task.safely.create!(name: hash["name"],
                            category: hash["category"],
                            ... );
```

I'm just wondering if it is possible to simplify this code and pass Ruby Hash to create!() method of Mongoid::Document ?

Something like this:

```
Task.safely.create!(hash)
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Sorry for dark problem.

Comment: looks like current `mongoid` removed `#safely` method for the `#with` one. At least that's what I see ATM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Task.safely.create!(name: hash["name"], category: hash["category"], ...)
```

is exactly the same as this:

```
Task.safely.create!({name: hash["name"], category: hash["category"], ...})
```

which is the same as this:

```
h = { name: hash['name'], ... }
Task.safely.create!(h)
```

So you can probably just do this:

```
Task.safely.create!(hash)
```

When you do something like this:

```
o.m(:a => 'b', :c => 'd')
```

Ruby notices that you're supply a Hash literal without the usual `{...}` wrapping and adds it for you; this sort of thing works at the end of any argument list:

```
o.m(a, b, :c => 'd', :e => 'f')
```

is the same as:

```
o.m(a, b, { :c => 'd', :e => 'f' })
```

Comment: Thank. Shame on me. I did't realized that it is a hash.

Comment: @demas: The hardest things to see are familiar things right in front of your face :)